# Hide subset of background-images until children() are fully loaded with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, list, background, preloading

I have some articles, each of them containig a list with multiple list items. Every list item has a background-image defined. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<article>
  <ul>
    <li><!-- background-image--></li>
    <li><!-- background-image--></li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

I would like to hide those list items until every image is loaded and im trying to do so for each article.

My first attempt was to use two nested loops but it feels a bit akward and complicated.

```
function preloader() {

    $('article').each( function(i) {        

        $(this).addClass('loading');

        var childNum = $(this).find('ul li').size();

        $(this).find('ul li').each( function(n) {

            var bgurl = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)|"|'/g,'');

            $('<img/>').attr('src', bgurl).load(function() {

                if (n == childNum) {

                    // remove class .loading from current article
                }

            });                             
            n++;
        });
    });
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this ?

Comment: just updated my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start them with `visibility:hidden` and show them when the `window.load` event fires.

**CSS**

```
.loading li{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<article class="loading">
  <ul>
    <li><!-- background-image--></li>
    <li><!-- background-image--></li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

and **jQuery**

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('article.loading').removeClass('loading');
});
```

---

If you want to show the images in each article as its own images have loaded then your code is pretty close, but you can improve with the following

- handle the `error` event as well
- cache your selections
- bind the `load` and `error` events before setting the `src` to correctly handle cached images

Here is an implementation

```
$(function () {
    var articles = $('article').addClass('loading');
    var urlRegExp = /(url\([\'\"]?)([^\'\"]+)/gi;

    articles.each(function(){
        var article = $(this),
            images = $('li', article).map(function(){
                return $(this).css('background-image').split(urlRegExp)[2];
            }).get(),
            imageCount = images.length;

        $.each(images, function(index, url){
           var img = new Image();
            $(img).on('load error', function(){
                imageCount--;
                if (imageCount === 0){
                    article.removeClass('loading');
                }
            })[0].src = url;
        });

    });
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/2ATHQ/

Comment: ok. i got it. thats pretty straight forward. i’ll try to implement it that way. thank you very much.